# Pandas: in memory sorting hdf5 files

Tags: pandas, hdf5, pytables

I have the following problem:

I have a set several hdf5 files with similar data frames which I want to sort globally based on multiple columns.

My input is the file names and an ordered list of columns I want to use for sorting. 
The output should be a single hdf5 file containing all the sorted data.

Each file can contain millions of rows. I can afford loading a single file in memory but not the entire dataset.

Naively I would like first to copy all the data in a single hdf5 file (which is not difficult) and then find out a way to do in memory sorting of this huge file.

Is there a quick way to sort in memory a pandas datastructure stored in an hdf5 file based on multiple columns?

I have already seen ptrepack but it seems to allow you sorting only on a single column.

Comment: Why do you actually need to sort the resulting file by more than one column? You can simply index in a query.

Comment: Hi @Jeff, what do you mean exactly with index in a query? Thanks

Comment: why don't u show some code of what you are doing

Comment: I am currently using a completely different strategy; I push all files one by one in a database table and then I retrieve the data I want sorted on the fly with pandas sql interface and an sql query.

Comment: if that works for you gr8