# Indexing and Data Columns in Pandas/PyTables

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#indexing

I'm really confused about this concept of Data columns in Pandas HDF5 IO. Plus there's very little to no information about it to be found on googling it either. Since I'm diving into Pandas in a large project which involves HDF5 storage, I'd like to be clear about such concepts.

The docs  say:

> You can designate (and index) certain columns that you want to be able
>   to perform queries (other than the indexable columns, which you can
>   always query). For instance say  you want to perform this common
>   operation, on-disk, and return just the frame that matches this query.
>   You can specify data_columns = True to force all columns to be
>   data_columns

This is confusing:

1. `other than the indexable columns, which you can always query`: What are 'indexable' columns? aren't all columns 'indexable'? What does this term mean?
2. `For instance say  you want to perform this common operation, on-disk, and return just the frame that matches this query.` How is that different from normal querying on a Pytable; with or without any indexes of `data_columns`?
3. What is the fundamental difference between a non-indexed, indexed, and data_column column?

Comment: I was having the same issue, with using `HDFStore.select_column` function. Found this only after figuring out that the column needed to be set in `data_columns`. This issue on github delves further into this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21188

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just try it.

```
In [22]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2),columns=['A','B'])

In [23]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

In [24]: store.append('df_only_indexables',df)

In [25]: store.append('df_with_data_columns',df,data_columns=True)

In [26]: store.append('df_no_index',df,data_columns=True,index=False)

In [27]: store
Out[27]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/df_no_index                     frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->5,ncols->2,indexers->[index],dc->[A,B])
/df_only_indexables              frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->5,ncols->2,indexers->[index])          
/df_with_data_columns            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->5,ncols->2,indexers->[index],dc->[A,B])

In [28]: store.close()
```

- you automatically get the index of the stored frame as a queryable column. By default NO other columns can be queried.
- If you specify `data_columns=True` or `data_columns=list_of_columns`, then these are stored separately and can then be subsequently queried.
- If you specify `index=False` then a `PyTables` index is not automatically created for the queryable column (eg. the `index` and/or `data_columns`).

To see the actual indexes being created (the `PyTables` indexes), see the output below. `colindexes` defines which columns have an actual `PyTables` index created. (I have truncated it somewhat).

```
/df_no_index/table (Table(5,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "A": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "B": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=2)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (2730,)
  /df_no_index/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 15 attributes:
   [A_dtype := 'float64',
    A_kind := ['A'],
    B_dtype := 'float64',
    B_kind := ['B'],
    CLASS := 'TABLE',
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := 0.0,
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'A',
    FIELD_2_FILL := 0.0,
    FIELD_2_NAME := 'B',
    NROWS := 5,
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.7',
    index_kind := 'integer']
/df_only_indexables/table (Table(5,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": Float64Col(shape=(2,), dflt=0.0, pos=1)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (2730,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
  /df_only_indexables/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 11 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'TABLE',
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := 0.0,
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'values_block_0',
    NROWS := 5,
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.7',
    index_kind := 'integer',
    values_block_0_dtype := 'float64',
    values_block_0_kind := ['A', 'B']]
/df_with_data_columns/table (Table(5,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "A": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "B": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=2)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (2730,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "A": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "B": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
  /df_with_data_columns/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 15 attributes:
   [A_dtype := 'float64',
    A_kind := ['A'],
    B_dtype := 'float64',
    B_kind := ['B'],
    CLASS := 'TABLE',
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := 0.0,
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'A',
    FIELD_2_FILL := 0.0,
    FIELD_2_NAME := 'B',
    NROWS := 5,
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.7',
    index_kind := 'integer']
```

So if you want to query a column, make it a `data_column`. If you don't then they will be stored in blocks by dtype (faster / less space).

You normally always want to index a column for retrieval, BUT, if you are creating and then appending multiple files to a single store, you usually turn off the index creation and do it at the end (as this is pretty expensive to create as you go).

See [the cookbook](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/cookbook.html#hdfstore) for a menagerie of questions.

Comment: What is the use of setting index=True? It seems to me that I can set data_columns=True, index=False, and I can still query the table using its columns

Comment: sure you can but you won't actually get the benefit of having an index causing a linear scan for any query. index=False is useful when appending, eg multiply appending then construct the index is more efficient that appending with an index (for large amounts of data)

Comment: how do I construct an index after finish appending? I couldn't find an example on the pandas documentation? Thank you for your help.

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893370/ptrepack-sortby-needs-full-index

Comment: if you would like to add to the cookbook would be gr8 (do a pull request)

Comment: Do you mean adding this question to the cookbook in http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/cookbook.html#hdfstore/ ? Sure

Comment: yep question with mini example

Comment: I don't see the index option in docs of `append`, `put` or `to_hdf`. Perhaps there's been changes?