# Pandas HDFStore for out-of-core Sequential read/write of sets with variable sizes

Tags: python, pandas, large-files

I want to read and write data to hdf5 file incrementally because I can't fit the data into memory.

The data to read/write is sets of integers. I only need to read/write the sets sequentially. No need for random access. Like I read set1, then set2, then set3, etc.

The problem is that I can't retrieve the sets by index.

```
import pandas as pd    
x = pd.HDFStore('test.hf', 'w', append=True)
a = pd.Series([1])
x.append('dframe', a, index=True)
b = pd.Series([10,2])
x.append('dframe', b, index=True)
x.close()

x = pd.HDFStore('test.hf', 'r')
print(x['dframe'])
y=x.select('dframe',start=0,stop=1)
print("selected:", y)
x.close()
```

Output:

```
0     1
0    10
1     2
dtype: int64
selected: 0    1
dtype: int64
```

It doesn't select my 0th set, which is `{1,10}`

Comment: `index=False` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714549/indexing-and-data-columns-in-pandas-pytables

Comment: you can simply do this: `y=x.select('dframe',start=0,stop=1+1)`

Comment: @MaxU. But that means I know that the set has two elements before I read from the file, which is not the case. I don't know the size of the set when I read the file.

Comment: in this case you should use `store.select('dframe', where="...")` as you did in your answer

Answer (score 1):

This way works. But I really don't know how fast is this.

And does this scan the whole file to find rows with the index?

That would be quite a waste of time.

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.HDFStore('test.hf', 'w', append=True, format="table", complevel=9)
a = pd.Series([1])
x.append('dframe', a, index=True)
b = pd.Series([10,2])
x.append('dframe', b, index=True)
x.close()

x = pd.HDFStore('test.hf', 'r')
print(x['dframe'])
y=x.select('dframe','index == 0')
print('selected:')
for i in y:
    print(i)
x.close()
```

Output:

```
0     1
0    10
1     2
dtype: int64
selected:
1
10
```

Comment: using `data_columns=True` - is a correct approach, but you should also create your HDF store with `table` format - `pd.HDFStore('test.hf', mode='w', format='table', append=True)`

Comment: you may want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41555615/5741205) for some performance testing...

Comment: @MaxU 755ms per cycle is just so bad... had to do like 759997 cycles, and I only need to read the sets sequentially instead of random access. If I write my own code for saving/reading sequentially, it can be faster.

Comment: I'd suggest you to open a new question, provide __reproducible__ sample data set (are you working with series in real life or with data frames?), explain what are you going to do. What `cycles` are you talking about - are you sure you need cycles at all?

Comment: yup. writing the binary io code now. probably will take half a day. oh, but then it will get moved to code review because it is "code that works as intended"